# Creating tensorflow dataset from pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, nlp

I want to do multi-class text classification with additional feature. I have a df with column text, feature, and label. My feature is a categorical variable with 2 possible outcomes. My label column is a categorical variable with 8 possible outcomes.
As these are both categorical variables with no order, I did one hot vector encoding.

I want to build a TensorFlow dataset and then do the embedding and define the model.
I found online a code snippet that transforms the df to a tensorflow dataset where binary text classification is done on df consisting of 2 columns: text and label (quiet different from my data). Here is this code snippet I found:

```
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=1024):
  df = dataframe.copy()
  labels = df.pop('Label')
  df = df["Text"]
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df, labels))
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
  return ds
```

I tried to update the function do that it can be applied in my case. Here is the code:

```
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, text_column_name, feature_column_names, label_column_names, shuffle=True, batch_size=1024):
    df = dataframe.copy()
    
    # Extract the text column and feature columns
    text_data = df[text_column_name]
    feature_data = df[feature_column_names]
    
    # Extract the labels
    labels = df[label_column_names]
    
    # Create a dataset with text data, feature data, and labels
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({'text': text_data,'features':feature_data}, labels))

    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
    
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    
    return ds
```

However, I came across the following error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

As far as I understood, this error occurs when I create `ds`because I am combining columns `text` and `feature`which are different dtypes: text is string and feature is a float.
I am not sure what to do to avoid this error?

Comment: I think this is not possible a tensor can and should have only one dtype. So a string and a float cant be present in a tensor. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor